# Symfony controller same function don't working

Tags: php, symfony

I got 2 controllers, advert and profile. I got 2 navs on view - my adverts and my profile.

In advert controller action is:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/my/adverts", name="my_advert_index")
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted("ROLE_USER");

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["owner" => $this->getUser()]);

    return $this->render("MyAdvert/index.html.twig", ["adverts" => $adverts]);
}
```

in profile controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("my/profile/details", name="my_profile_details")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function detailsAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted("ROLE_USER");

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $profile = $entityManager->getRepository(Profile::class)->findBy(["user" => $this->getUser()]);

    return $this->render("MyProfile/details.html.twig", [
        "profile" => $profile,
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

adverts in avert view are ok, but in proile view:

> Key "name" for array with keys "0" does not exist.

What happen? This is the same code, but profile controller don't send any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 $profile = $entityManager->getRepository(Profile::class)->findBy(["user" => $this->getUser()]);
```

With

```
$profile = $entityManager->getRepository(Profile::class)->findOneBy(["user" => $this->getUser()]);
```

I bet in your view you're doing something like `profile.name` while `findBy()` is returning you an array of result, even if you have only one result.

Comment: Glad it fixes your problem. Vote/Accept the answer to close your question once it's answered please (by your profile, I'd say you're not aware you have to) so it disapears from unsolved questions.